# how git synchronize between two different folder with same repository

Tags: git

[image]

See the picture above，every node indicate a commit

A repository when at `C` node, then clone this repository in two different folder `folderA/folderB`

At `folderA` for some reason rollback `C` node and do something change forward to `D` node, push to remote

Then i want `floderB` synchronize to remote and then run `git pull` command, it will auto merge

`folderA` log history

```
* dd0b2ef add file
* d795c47 first init
```

`folderB` log history

```
*   2d7dd9d Merge branch 'master' of http://.../git-test
|\
| * dd0b2ef add file
* | 186db65 second commit
|/
* d795c47 first init
```

how to let `folderB` also auto rollback to `B` not merge

Comment: `git reset B --hard`.

Comment: @ElpieKay yes, but how to let program auto to do this, check the repository has rollback operation, then run `git reset` rollback and `git pull` sync repository. Everytime when the repository has no rollback operation, just only run `git pull`, if it has we need human interference

Comment: `git fetch origin master && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correcly, you want `folderB` to exactly follow what happens on the `origin`. In that case, you can use

```
git fetch origin                 # Get updates from origin (but don't apply them)
git reset --hard origin/master   # Reset the working tree to match origin/master
git clean -fd                    # Remove all untracked files, so we match origin/master exactly
```